# Update character-extended field in sqlite database where least-significant digits/chars match

Tags: python, sqlite

I am writing a python script to extract information from a number of text files into a database. For simplicity, assume that the columns are `id` (primary key, a string of numbers stored as `text`), `name` (stored as `text`, not unique), and a bunch of other columns containing other data.

The script all works well, however at one point the `id` fields in the source files change from <=6 characters to 7 characters, with extra numbers added to the start of ids of existing records - so 12345 might become 2012345 (or 3312345, etc.). There seems to be no way to consistently determine what the added numbers will be, but the previous `id` is always still remaining as the least-significant *n* digits (where *n* = the length of the old `id`).

What I would like to do is create a sqlite query to be run at the point in the import where the `id`s change that updates the `id` to the new format where a) the `name` field is the same as an existing row where the new record's least significant digits match exactly the old id. I am struggling to write a query that does this, however - any ideas?

**EDIT:** As requested, example data:

Initial table:

```
+--------+-----------------+-------+
|   id   |      name       | other |
+--------+-----------------+-------+
| 277908 | Anderson, Jason | foo   |
|  10360 | Anderson, Jean  | bar   |
|  10371 | Anderson, John  | baz   |
|  57892 | Anderson, John  | qwe   |
+--------+-----------------+-------+
```

Then if we come across the record to be updated:

```
+---------+-----------------+-----+
| 1277908 | Anderson, Jason | asd |
+---------+-----------------+-----+
```

The id is updated and the table becomes:

```
+--------+-----------------+-------+
|   id   |      name       | other |
+--------+-----------------+-------+
|1277908 | Anderson, Jason | foo   |
|  10360 | Anderson, Jean  | bar   |
|  10371 | Anderson, John  | baz   |
|  57892 | Anderson, John  | qwe   |
+--------+-----------------+-------+
```

However if we then come across the record:

```
+---------+-----------------+-----+
| 2010360 | Anderson, Jean2 | zxc |
+---------+-----------------+-----+
```

Then the table isn't modified as the name doesn't match one in the record, and if we come across the record:

```
+---------+----------------+-----+
| 2010371 | Anderson, John | poi |
+---------+----------------+-----+
```

Then only the id with the matching least significant digits is updated and the table becomes:

```
+--------+-----------------+-------+
|   id   |      name       | other |
+--------+-----------------+-------+
|1277908 | Anderson, Jason | foo   |
|  10360 | Anderson, Jean  | bar   |
|2010371 | Anderson, John  | baz   |
|  57892 | Anderson, John  | qwe   |
+--------+-----------------+-------+
```

Note that here we are *only* updating the id fields - this is deliberate as this will be in a run-once conditional that will update the records at the point in the data where the id change happens. Other data will be updated or records added after this part has run.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired result. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Comment: @CL. Example added.

Comment: What is *n*? 5 or 6?

Comment: @CL. n=the length of the old id field, but the actual value varies. I think the smallest *n* is 2. The 'new' id is constantly n=7.

Comment: And how would you know which *n* to use?

Comment: @CL. It would be whatever the length of the old id is. So, the id gets replaced for any pair where e.g. `new_id[-len(old_id):] == old_id && old_name == new_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert that expression to SQL:

```sql
UPDATE MyTable
SET id = :Newid
WHERE :NewId != id
  AND substr(:NewId, -length(id)) = id
  AND name = :NewName
```

(This assumes that the `id` values are strings.)